# Any way to give variable 2 types?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a movie database that can hold up to 4 movies for some homework. I know I can easily make it have 4 variables (1 for each movie) but I was wondering if I could somehow have it so the same variable "movie" could have 2 types, int and string where i have movie1.setName etc

is there anyway to just have it as movie.setName and then somehow increase the movie number each time like a counter?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Interface2 extends MovieDatabase
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Movie movie1;
    Movie movie2;
    Movie movie3;
    Movie movie4;
    String name, director;
    int size, duration, option;
    int moviecount = 0;

    movie1 = new Movie();
    movie2 = new Movie();
    movie3 = new Movie();
    movie4 = new Movie();

do {
    System.out.println("Import first movie:(0), View Movies: (1),  Exit (9): ");
    option = console.nextInt();
    switch(option)
    {
        case 0: 
        if(moviecount <= 4)
        {
                System.out.print("name: ");
                name = console.next();
                movie1.setName (name);
                System.out.print("Director: ");
                director = console.next();
                movie1.setDirector (director);
                System.out.print("Size in MB: ");
                size = console.nextInt();
                movie1.setSize(size);
                System.out.print("Duration in minutes: ");
                duration = console.nextInt();
                movie1.setDuration(duration);
                moviecount++;
                break;
            }
        else
                System.out.print("Too many movies currently stored");
                break;

        case 1: System.out.print("Movies currently stored: ");
                System.out.print(movie1.getName());
                break;




} 
}
        while(option!=9);
}
}
```

Sorry if it is worded terribly, its hard to explain what I would like to do as I am new.

Comment: Use a List or array, please. Numbered variables are an anti-pattern

Comment: We aren't allowed to use arrays. No way to do it without arrays?

Comment: I hate homework ... the typical conundrum - I want to do something wrong the correct way ... is like saying "I wanna eat - but shouldn't be using my mouth" ... Where are we? Zelda-land with riddles and magicians?

Comment: `We aren't allowed to use arrays` that sounds like you have terrible teacher or its either you are afraid to use arrays.

Comment: Either way - you ask how to use an index (int) and set content array[index] , and maybe use a loop ... so yeah - your thinking is right - but that is exactly what an array is.

Comment: @Enzokie actually we haven't learned arrays yet in class. So no, I am not afraid to use them, the teacher is not terrible, its just some students have had prior experience and she decided it would be unfair. Thanks for your helpful comment though, muchly appreciated.

Comment: @SamHoward why I said that because you have tackled a portion of the OOP concept but not arrays? But I wont insist that. To answer really your question : There is a way of doing that, by storing the values in 1 string variable and parse it although its a bit complicated that using arrays and it gives a bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

use some array

```
Movie[] movies = new Movie[4];
```

then `movies[0]=new Movies();`

then `movies[0].setName();`

note that every array starts with index 0, so 4 Movie object will be 0,1,2,3

Comment: We aren't allowed to use arrays. No way to do it without arrays?

Comment: @SamHoward even the ArrayList class is an array so you just have to declare 4 Movies because Array can be the solution for your problem, but as you said your not allowed you can also loop array like what you are saying

Comment: @ abcOfjava Sorry I dont full understand that last part. Have I accidently used arrays? We haven't learnt about them yet which is why we cant use them. Should I leave it the way I have it and just repeat for each new movie?

Comment: @SamHoward yes just leave it the way you have it because you are not allowed to use array.What I meant on my last comment is that you can loop the array element to be able for each array element to have a value

Comment: Ok but now I run into the issue that I cannot add an error message if there is more than 4 movies. Since the user will have the option to add each movie separately from the menu part the moviecount variable becomes useless.

Comment: try putting some if..else statement if(movieCount==1) movie1.setName else if(movieCount==2) movie2.setName down through the movie4 then if movieCount >4 Error movie count full @SamHoward

Comment: @SamHoward do not allow the user to input any values when movieCount>4 instead display some error message also follow the naming convention look at this website for naming convention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: One of the functions required in the program is to be able to delete movies if I delete Movie1 for example after inputting 4 movies then I will not be able to add Movoe1 again since moviecount==3.

Comment: @SamHoward have you not thought about the logic `movieCount--`?

Comment: Yes but say if I delete Movie1 and do moviecount-- wouldn't moviecount==3?

Comment: @SamHoward then after movieCount==3 set the movie3 to become null to be able to allow the user to input again something like `movie3 = null` right away you should assign null value at the beginning of if..else statement then after that `movie3=new Movie();`